# Angular2 ngFor elements with Material Design Lite

Tags: angular, material-design, material-design-lite

I'm struggling to make Material Design Lite component to work with dynamically added elements via *ngFor. I understand that I need to call componentHandler.upgradeElement, but where do I put this call? I was trying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421919/integrating-material-design-lite-with-angular2) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33386129/how-to-encapsulate-dynamically-added-elements-in-angular-2) directives but they don't seem to work. 
Specifically, I need mdl-menu on each item of my array. Any suggestions on where to look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR;** You need to call componentHandler.upgradeElement after the elements have been injected into the DOM. An approach I've used in the past is described in the example below.

**EDIT** If you want a declarative solution [this approach here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34421919/integrating-material-design-lite-with-angular2#answer-35451821) seem like a pretty good one, but I have not used it myself.

I created a service that wraps the Material Lite componentHandler

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export interface ComponentHandler {
    upgradeDom();

}

declare var componentHandler: ComponentHandler;


@Injectable()
export class MaterialService {
    handler: ComponentHandler;
    constructor() {
        this.handler = componentHandler;
    }

    // render on next tick
    render() {
        setTimeout(() => { this.handler.upgradeDom(); }, 0);
    }

}
```

Then you call the service's render function after the component has injected the elements into the DOM. In your case this is after the `*ngFor`

This is a very contrived example but demonstrates "where" to call render

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from 'services/data.service';
import { MaterialService } from 'services/material.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-thing',
    templateUrl: `
       <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let item of data">
              {{data}}
            </li>
       </ul>
    `
})
export class ThingComponent implements OnInit {
    data: string[]
    constructor(
        private service: DataService,
        private material: MaterialService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.service.getData()
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data;
            this.material.render();
        });
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem: MDL does not watch dynamically created DOM element.

Solution: MDL library adds componentHandler property onto Window object.
execute the below code inside ngOnInit() method of the component in which you are adding element dynamically.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  window['componentHandler'].upgradeDom();
}, 0);
```